# Unable to find target for local link QUrl( "file:///tmp/wktemp-42b3a7ac-.......html#435364" )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using 
pdfkit 0.6.2
wkhtmltopdf (0.1.2) 
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.3) to convert HTML file to PDF in a ruby script. I am getting the following error:

`Unable to find target for local link   QUrl( "file:///tmp/wktemp-42b3a7ac-5dd4-4201-95fe-e132c554b967.html#499958" )`

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I am generating hundreds of html files and converting them to pdf. But these errors are showing for some of the files only.

Has anyone faced this error before? Need help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Reason Found**. This error is thrown when the html file does not have the "div" the link is pointing to. In the url above `#499958` is the div id which is removed using JS according to my need. So when html is being converted to pdf, the wkhtmltopdf cannot find the div with id='499958' and throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

When I use this library in C# it suffers from the same problem.

Preprocess your HTML resolving references to resources (CSS or JPG files) and replace the references with absolute file-system paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Peter. I am already referencing with absolute file-system paths. The problem still persists.

Comment: sorry for posting this so late. I found the reason for this error. I wrote it as a comment above. Thanks!